# Hide blenderkit search bar

Tags: add-on, blenderkit

BlenderKit is a useful addon that lets you search for assets to add to your scene. But now I have found what I wanted and I would like to make this search bar go away, since it's taking up unnecessary space:

[image]

How can I do that without restarting Blender?

Comment: you could e.g. just uncheck it under add-ons

Comment: @Chris that works, thanks. It's not *super* convenient though, as I'll have to go into the preferences to re-enable it each time I want to use it. It's better than nothing if there's no other solution

Comment: You can always use the Blenderkit tab on the N panel!

Comment: @JohnEason: i don't understand? where can i hide that searchbar there?

Comment: tbh i don't like that permanent search bar as well...and the second thing is the aggressive loading in the background each time when starting Blender even if you don't use it...and at least in my versions it was pretty buggy.

Comment: @JohnEason: ah, that's great, didn't know that. I wish i could show/not show that bar in the N-panel settings to easily access it instead of going to add-ons, search it, open preferences and do it there...

Comment: I've added an answer now showing the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the search bar under <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Addons</kbd> in the Blenderkit settings under <kbd>GUI settings</kbd> by unchecking <kbd>Show Blenderkit search in 3D view header</kbd>.

[image]

The search facility is still available  in the <kbd>N-panel</kbd> sidebar in a slightly different format as shown below. You can show or hide the result Assetbar by clicking the eye icon beside the search field.

[image]